# Предложение является спп?

Tags: спп, синтаксический-разбор

Весла взлетали и падали сами, будто бы работал ими пьяный или сонный человек.

Сравнительно-объектное СПП. Верно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Верно. Здесь передается семантика сравнения.